# how do i write a keypress callback?

Tags: callback, raspberry-pi3, python-3.4

I'm trying to write a piece of code for Raspberry Pi in python 3.4.2 that uses callbacks to trigger certain events.

Currently I'm making use of a nifty GPIO command (GPIO.add_event_detect) along with a try/except rule that makes the script pause and wait until something happens.

I want to do something similar at the same time for a keyboard button press (not bothered which one right now), is there a way to do this that's similar to the GPIO.add_event_detect?

an example in code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

receiverPin = 14
quitButton = 17

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(receiverPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(quitButton, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

#FUNCTION ACTIVATED BY DESIRED CODE#
def activate(channel):
    #do stuff#

def direct_hit(channel):
    #do stuff#

GPIO.add_event_detect(receiverPin, GPIO.BOTH, callback=direct_hit)

#DESIRED CODE BLOCK
keypress.add_event_detect(KEYPRESS_ENTER, callback=activate)

try:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(quitButton, GPIO.FALLING)
    print("Exiting")
    GPIO.cleanup()
    quit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Is there a way to do this? bear in mind I am self taught(poorly).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some research for you and found this library: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_press which have event method `on_press`

Just add:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.on_press = yourCallback
```

Hope it will help you.